# One-liner for wrapping some text around members of a list of numbers

Tags: regex, unicode, stata

Suppose I have a sequence of strings that looks something like this:

```
1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78
```

I would like to turn it into

```
F(1) F(10) F(46565) F(5968678) F(3) F(567) F(78)
```

Is there a regex one-liner that will accomplish that in Stata with an arbitary number of elements?

I tried:

```
. display ustrregexra("1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78","([:digit:]){1,}","XXX")
XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
```

and

```
. display ustrregexra("1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78","([:digit:]){1,}","F(&)")
F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&)
```

and

```
. display ustrregexra("1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78","[0-9]{1,}","F(&)")
F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&) F(&)
```

In VI, this seems to do the trick:

```
.s/[0-9]\{1,}/F(&)/g
```

Is there any equivalent of that in Stata for the unicode or vanilla regex functions? Stata's ustrregex* functions are bases on the [ICU regex engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) according to [this comment](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1327564-new-program-for-regular-expressions?p=1327779#post1327779) by a StataCorp programmer.

Comment: As a *generic* regex, you can do `s/(\d+)/F(\1)/g` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BdZYI/1/)

Comment: The following works with the example at hand: `dis subinstr("F("+"1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78"+")"," ", ") F(",.)`

Comment: @RobertPicard this is not a regex. The OP asks for a regex specifically.

Comment: OK, here's a regex version: `dis ustrregexra("F("+"1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78"+")"," ", ") F(")`

Comment: @RobertPicard this is the same thing. It works but it is not a regex in the traditional sense. It is string substitution. Clever trick though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Stata does not support regular expressions of the kind you mention.
2. Its regular expression functions cannot handle substitutions such as `F(\1)`.

There is only one way to do it in one (rather long) line:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate str = "1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78"

local regex ([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)[ ]([0-9]*)

generate new_str  = "F(" + regexs(1) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(2) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(3) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(4) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(5) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(6) + ") " + ///
                    "F(" + regexs(7) + ")" if regexm(str, "`regex'")

. list, abbreviate(10)

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                         str                                            new_str |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78   F(1) F(10) F(46565) F(5968678) F(3) F(567) F(78) |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can obviously generalise this and make it a "true" one liner by writing a small program.

---

**EDIT:**

The following is a generalization that also exploits Robert's trick:

```
program define foo, rclass
local string `1'
local string = ustrregexra("`string'","\D"," ")
local string = ustrtrim(itrim("`string'"))
local string = ustrregexra("F("+"`string'"+")"," ", ") F(")
return local old_string `1'
return local new_string `string'
end

foo "1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78"

return list

macros:
         r(new_string) : "F(1) F(10) F(46565) F(5968678) F(3) F(567) F(78)"
         r(old_string) : "1 10 46565 5968678 3 567 78"

foo "1xcvb10gh46565sdda5968678luiy3f567kl78"

return list

macros:
         r(new_string) : "F(1) F(10) F(46565) F(5968678) F(3) F(567) F(78)"
         r(old_string) : "1xcvb10gh46565sdda5968678luiy3f567kl78"
```

Comment: +1 I was aware of this, but it requires knowing the number of elements, which is something that I was not very clear about in the original post. I think your suggestion of a small program is the right one, where I can code that cardinality calculation in. I really thought the newer unicode regex engine would be able to handle this.

Comment: Thanks and i agree - I have always found regex in Stata to be sub-par. The lack of detailed documentation i suspect plays an important role, In the end, i decided that instead of guessing the quirks of Stata's regex engine it is best to switch to Python.

Comment: I think creating a small program is trivial and the most flexible way forward.
Robert's clever solution is fine for your use case here but in more complex cases
such as a string of the kind `1xcvb10gh46565sdda5968678luiy3f567kl78` it cannot
do what you want ***and*** keep the letters. This is because it relies on simple string
substitution (in this case a space).